# Search different audio files for equal short samples

Tags: audio, comparison, fft, sampling

Consider multiple (at least two) different audio-files, like several different mixes or remixes. Naively I would say, it must be possible to detect samples, especially the vocals, that are almost equal in two or more of the files, of course only then, if the vocal samples aren't modified, stretched, pitched, reverbed too much etc.

So with what kind of algorithm or technique this could be done? Let's say, the user would try to set time markers in all files best possible, which describe the data windows to compare, containing the presumably equal sounds, vocals etc.

I know that no direct approach, trying to directly compare wav data in any way is useful. But even if I have the frequency domain data (e.g. from FFT), I would have to use a comparison algorithm that kind of shifts the comparing-windows through time scale, since I cannot assume the samples, I want to find, are time sync over all files.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you have any success in comparing audio files?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is possible !!

You can use one technique called LSH (locality sensitive hashing), is very robust.

another way to do this is try make spectrogram analysis in your audio files ...

*Construct database song*

```
1. Record your Full Song
2. Transform the sound to spectrum
3. slice your Spectrogram in chunk and get three or four high Frequencies
4. Store all the points
```

*Match the song*

```
1. Record one short sample.
2. Transform the sound into another spectrum 
3. slice your Spectrogram in chunk and get three or four hight Frequencies
4. Compare the collected frequencies with your database song.
5. your match is the song with have the high hit !
```

you can see here how make ..

http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=EN&sl=pt&u=http://ederwander.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/audio-fingerprint-em-python/

ederwander

Comment: Unfortunately this is more like audio fingerprinting, which is not what I want. I KNOW, that my two samples are familiar and I want kind of Vocal-Excerption respectively Vocal-Remove, not identifying that a database song matches a sample.